# windows 7 file explorer crashes after mkdir via git bash

Tags: windows-7, bash, windows-explorer, git, git-bash

My environment:

- Windows 7
- Git v1.9.0

Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. open a folder in windows explorer
2. right click in that folder and select "Git Bash"
3. execute: "mkdir test" in the git bash window that pops up
4. windows explorer stops responding

If I `cd` into the folder instead of going directly there with the right click method, explorer won't crash.

Comment: capture a crash dump and share it: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: @magicandre1981 I followed the directions in your pastebin: ran the `.reg` file, crashed explorer, but I couldn't find a dump file in C.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your Git? Maybe what is actually crashing is Git and explorer crashes b/c of that.

Comment: do you see the folder C:\localdumps? Is the service "Windows Error reporting" running? You can also register procdump as post mortem debugger (**procdump -i C:\localdumps**) to create dumps: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

Comment: As I said in my answer this is because of crappy git shell context menu extension. Just don't use it or fill a bug for 'git for windows' developers

Answer (score 0):

Update Git to 1.9.2, there was issue git-cheetah plug-in

To fix this problem in git 1.9.0 you must uninstall/reinstall. On reinstalling select the following options.

```
[x] Windows Explorer integration
   (*) Simple context menu (Registry based)
     [x] Git Bash Here
     [x] Git GUI Here
( ) Advanced context menu (git-cheetah plug-in)
```

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083422/git-bash-1-9-0-using-windows-explorer-intergration-crashes-folder-explorer)